# SQL how to pass sysdate in LIKE command?

Tags: sql, oracle

The result of query

```
Select SYSDATE from DUAL
```

is

```
19-JUL-19
```

How to pass this date in like command to extract all the tuples of today's date

The table look like this

```
ID             MSG_TYPE       CollectionDate
515587         GenOut         21-FEB-19 04.09.57.325772000 PM
515588         GenOut         19-JUL-19 01.06.15.307068000 PM
515589         GenOut         22-AUG-18 03.20.15.307069290 PM
515590         GenOut         19-JUL-19 12.03.09.873288000 PM
```

Expected result

```
ID             MSG_TYPE       CollectionDate
515588         GenOut         19-JUL-19 01.06.15.307068000 PM
515590         GenOut         19-JUL-19 12.03.09.873288000 PM
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `CollectionDate`?

Comment: `LIKE` is for string values, not for dates or timestamps - why are you storing a timestamp value in a `varchar` column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `LIKE`.

One way is to truncate `collection_date`, but that will disable index created on that column. Though, if there aren't many rows in that table, you won't notice the difference.

```
select * from your_table where trunc(collection_date) = trunc(sysdate)
```

A safer way is to

```
select * from your_table
where collection_date >= trunc(sysdate)
  and collection_date <  trunc(sysdate + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this 
select * from your_table order by CollectionDate;

Further, you may use ASC/DESC to sort data according to the requirement.
asc : default
desc: order by CollectionDate desc

Hope it helps!

Thanks!